# How to create a textbox that outputs in <p> </p> format (HTML)

Tags: html, text, textbox, output

How do I create a textbox that outputs in `<p> </p>` format?
For example when someone enters his name, his name appears on another page.

Comment: Can we see your HTML? Are you posting the textbox using a FORM and then displaying the variable on another page?

Comment: Only using HTML? Are you using any PHP or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input name="name" id="name" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#name").change(function() {
    $("#idOfPElementWhichYouWantToEdit").text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Please note that this requires jQuery, a javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP and a FORM:

```
<?php

$text=isset($_POST['text'])?$_POST['text']:false;

if ($text) {
  echo"<p>".$text."</p>";
}

?>

<form action="" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post">
  <textarea name="text"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```